# Record audio discordjs

Tags: javascript, audio, discord, discord.js, recording

So discord.js includes audio recording in vc's and me and my friends want to host a podcast in a vc. We've already made visuals and everything but we cant get it to record sound but the way discord.js does it is they stop the stream and export the second a person stops talking. Which makes you end up with hundreds of audio files. Is there any way to continuously record everyone at once and end only when told to?

https://discordjs.guide/voice/receiving-audio.html#basic-usage

Comment: What's wrong with the `'manual'` mode they described in the link you posted?

Comment: It’s fine but I don’t see any documentation on how to stop it.

Comment: Probably [`VoiceConnection#disconnect()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceConnection?scrollTo=disconnect)?

Comment: I guess that would work thx!